# Getting Internal Error - SP2010 - WSP Builder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wspbuilder

I've a SP2010 Enterprise installed in Win Server 2008 R2. After i create a web app i'm able to browse the application.

After i deploy a custom solution (which is working fine in MOSS 2007) through WSP Builder Extensions for 2010 using VS 2010 i'm getting

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

I'm not able to see anything in IIS Logs, SharePoint Logs and Event Viewer. I guess whatever works in MOSS will work in SP 2010.

How can i track and fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSPBuilder for SP2010 is still in beta, you probalby should use Visual Studio 2010 Sharepoint templates instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling verbose errors?
See [link](http://vspug.com/michael/2007/06/28/sharepoint-under-the-hood-see-real-error-description-and-callstack-stack-trace/)